# Compatibility of PHP 7.4.21 with MySQL 8.x

Tags: php, mysql, upgrade, mysql-8.0

I plan upgrade my MySQL to version 8.x and just find this article: https://www.ma-no.org/en/networking/databases/mysql-8-0-is-now-fully-supported-in-php-7-4

Based on its description, auth_plugin_caching_sha2_password is supported in PHP 7.4.21 and I just checked my instance and confirm this.

However, it seems that there is another issue with mysqli.so. I don't know what it is for. But it seems that I need to modify php.ini to make it work. Is that true?

So before I perform upgrade, need I modify php.ini based on the above article?